# Problem with large numbers of data update with cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wrote a query. I am editing data from a registered table of about 37000 and updating it with a cursor. It goes wrong result when I exceed a certain number. This record count is about 12800-12900.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I'm so confused.

Is there any possibility of a restriction when working with the cursor?

Comment: Table and query are too long. If you want to look at the codes I can send link.

Comment: Please provide relevant table layout, indeces and your SQL statement for proper analysis.  Your row counts are probably not the problem.

Comment: Codes: http://www.dipolpos.com/txt/SSHYB.txt

Comment: Table: https://ibb.co/5YmPPDH

Comment: You can print the values for all the records or just add try catch and on catch block print the all variables value then you able to find the exact problem. I think there is some data issue

Comment: Is the “TOP 11998” record limit in the cursor dataset in the code intentional?

Comment: It is not very clear what exactly goes wrong - do you get an unexpected result or do you get an error code? I think you would be better served if you tried to explain what the purpose of the code is. Looking at it it looks not deterministic to me. You start by setting Ckey, using an order by, and your loop compares it to Cokey, but the cursor is not ordered, so you cannot know the order the rows will be processed. Just because you use and order by when inserting does not guarantee that you get the same order when retrieving. 
Please specify what goes wrong, and what you are trying to di.

Answer (score 0):

```
BelgeNo = DocumentNo
CoKey = Company's unique number
Kapsam = type of document
Durumu = status (for document valid=1 invalid=0)
BitisTarihi = End date of the document
```

Original table has about 37000 records and mixed. I tried to group for 'CoKey' and 'Kapsam' the data in the original table with the following query.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.BelgeNo, A.CoKey, A.Kapsam, A.Durumu, A.BitisTarihi
FROM Sshyb A
INNER JOIN (SELECT CoKey, Kapsam
            FROM Sshyb
            GROUP BY CoKey, Kapsam
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B
ON A.CoKey = B.CoKey AND A.Kapsam = B.Kapsam
ORDER BY A.Kapsam, A.CoKey
```

But I may be making a mistake in this query. The number of records is about 25000 when the query runs coz of 'having'. (i have to do this for single records) anyway

Table: ibb.co/5YmPPDH

After that i have cases:

```
if CoKey = Kapsam

biggest 'end date' must be true, others must be false (in the group as selected in the picture)

if dates are before today all should be wrong in the group

if CoKey != Kapsam

Switch to other group and check same case
```

In order to do this, I use the cursor as in the query. I am trying to find the groups with the temporary table and update the above. But when it goes above about 12000 records, the update process does not work as I designed it. I am not receiving an error but the update is incorrect.

Comment: Guys i solved the problem i was my silly fault. Sorry about that. Thanks for your comments.